# Keeping history of hash/anchor changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fragment-identifier

I'm currently implementing a JavaScript library that keeps track of the history of changes to the hash part in the address bar. The idea is that you can keep a state in the hash part, and then use the back button to go back to the previous state.

In most of the recent browsers, this is automatic and you only have to poll the `location.hash` property for changes (In IE8 you don't even have to do that; you simply attach a function to the `onhashchange` event.)

**What I'm wondering is**, what different methods are there to keep track of the history? I've implemented functionality that has been tested to work in Internet Explorer 6/7/8, Firefox and Chrome, but what about other browsers? Here's the ways I currently keep the history:

***Edit***: See my answer below instead for a walk-through of the various browsers.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First of all, thanks to you guys who answered! =)

I've now done a lot more research and I believe I'm satisfied with my implementation. Here are the results of my research.

First of all, [my finished `Hash` library](http://github.com/blixt/js-hash). It's a stand-alone library with no dependencies. It has two functions: `Hash.init(callback, iframe)` and `Hash.go(newHash)`. The callback function is called whenever the hash changes with the new hash as its first argument, and as its second argument a flag indicating whether the callback is called due to initial state (`true`) or an actual change to the hash (`false`).

> [Hash.js](http://github.com/blixt/js-hash/raw/master/Hash.js) (MIT license)

I also made a jQuery plugin for making it easier to use. Adds a global `hashchange` event as well. See example in source code for how to use it.

> [jquery.hash.js](http://github.com/blixt/js-hash/raw/master/jquery/jquery.hash.js) (MIT license)

To see them in use, go to my JavaScript "realm" page:

> [Blixt's JavaScript realm](http://blixt.org/js)

#### Internet Explorer 8

Smooooth cruisin'! Just smack on one o' them `onhashchange` events to the `window` object (using `attachEvent`) and get the `location.hash` value in the event handler.

It doesn't matter if the user clicks a link with a hash, or if you set the hash programmatically; history is kept perfectly.

#### Chrome, Firefox, Safari 3+, Opera 8+

Smooth cruisin'! Just poll for changes to the `location.hash` property using `setInterval` and a function.

History works perfectly. For Opera, I set `history.navigationMode` to `'compatible'`. To be honest, I'm not sure what it does, I did it on recommendation from a comment in the YUI code.

***Note***: Opera needs some additional testing, but it has worked fine for me so far.

***Surprise quirk bonus! (Can it be?!)*** It turns out that Firefox (only confirmed in 3.5+) decodes the `location.hash` property, so this can trigger a `hashchange` event twice (first for the encoded version then for the unencoded version.) There is a new version of my Hash.js library that takes this into account by using the `location.href` property instead (changes provided by Aaron Ogle.)

#### Internet Explorer 6, 7

Now it gets nastier. The navigation history in older Internet Explorer versions ignore hash changes. To work around this, the commonly accepted solution is to create an `iframe` and set its content to the new hash. This creates a new entry in the navigation history. When the user goes back, this changes the content of the `iframe` to its previous content. By detecting the change of content, you can get it and set it as the active hash.

Checking for changes to the `location.hash` property is still needed to manual changes to the current address. Beware of the quirks I've mentioned below, though.

While this solution seems to be the best one out there, it's still not perfect in Internet Explorer 6, which is a bit quirky about the back/forward buttons. Internet Explorer 7 works fine, though.

***Surprise quirk bonus #1!*** In Internet Explorer 6, whenever there's a question mark in the hash, this gets extracted and put in the `location.search` *property! It is removed from the* `location.hash` *property. If there is a real query string, however,* `location.search` *will contain that one instead, and you'll only be able to get the whole true hash by parsing the* `location.href` *property.*

***Surprise quirk bonus #2!*** If the `location.search` *property is set, any subsequent* `#` *characters will be removed from the* `location.href` *(and* `location.hash`*) property. In Internet Explorer 6 this means that whenever there's a question mark in the path or the hash, you'll experience this quirk. In Internet Explorer 7, this quirk only occurs when there's a question mark in the path. Don't you just love the consistency in Internet Explorer?*

***Surprise quirk bonus #3!*** If another element on the page has the same id as the value of a hash, that hash will totally mess up the history. So rule of thumb is to avoid hashes with the same id as any elements on the page. If the hashes are generated dynamically and may collide with ids, consider using a prefix/suffix.

#### Other browsers

Unless you've got an out-of-the-ordinary user base, you won't need to support more browsers. The browsers not listed above are in the <1% usage category.

Comment: "It's a stand-alone library with no dependencies."  - Thank you! This is great.

Comment: Obvious failing of this: hashchange fires when you click on a new link, iff the link has been created with your software (a plain 'a' is not sufficient, I believe, your code need to tamper with it), or if you visit from another page.  It *doesn't* fire on browser back and forward.  To do that, I think you need a timer to poll for changes, judging by other implementations.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but can someone elaborate on the details of the "Surprise quirk bonus #3"? What is exactly the issue? Do you have a test case demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the effort that you've put into this, I would assume that you've seen [YUI Browser History Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/), but just in case ...

They give a nice write up of their implementation, and I find their source code very readable.

Here's what it says about Opera

```
* location.hash is a bit buggy on Opera. I have seen instances where
* navigating the history using the back/forward buttons, and hence
* changing the URL, would not change location.hash. That's ok, the
* implementation of an equivalent is trivial ... more below
```

Searching the source I found some accomodations for Safari 1.x & 2.0 also. Seems like you'd be interested in it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, a few pieces of my code is inspired by their implementation. I did see their Safari implementation but I couldn't find a simple way to get it to work, and would have to increase the size of my code quite considerably, which is why I'm wondering if Safari 2 and below is still used by enough people to warrant support.

Comment: Safari 2 was at 0.5% in Jan of 2009 according to: http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?date=2009-01-31. So 1 in 200 as of 6 months ago.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I'll decide not to support Safari 2 then, because the code interferes with modern browsers unless browser sniffing is implemented... and that I dislike. =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your needs, but I have used the Really Simple History library (http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) for implementing something similar. You can see it here: http://whiteoak.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm after a light-weight way of simply keeping track of the hash value and supporting back/forward buttons, with the same behavior in all the commonly used browsers. RSH does not seem to be such a library, as it is over 9 kB when YUI-compressed and still depends on external libraries... My own library currently weighs in at 835 bytes compressed and works in IE6+, Firefox, Chrome and presumably Opera 8+ and Safari 3+ without dependencies... I'm mostly wondering if I'm missing any browsers and how to support them too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything mentioned about what I am about to say anywhere so I thought I'd share and see how common knowledge it is.

In IE (only verified in IE7), the history with the hash works correctly when there is a page element on the screen with an id equal to the hash.  For example, think of a table of contents (TOC) on a wiki page.  Each link in the TOC links to a hash of an id or anchor name element somewhere on the page:

```
<div id="TOC">
<a id="SampleHeaderLink" href="#SampleHeader">Sample Header</a>
</div>

<h2 id="SampleHeader">Sample Header</a>
```

So when SampleHeaderLink is clicked, the IE browser default setting is to navigate to SampleHeader and register the state in the history.  Using the back button and forward button works as expected.

However, if the SampleHeader div does not exist on the page, the browser only registers the url changing but does not create a new state for it.

Again, this is only verified in IE7.  And I don't know how common-knowledge this information is but I never found anything related when I was browsing to fix this very issue in my own application.

Comment: I do mention this – or rather, the flip side of it. If using the `iframe` approach, the history will be completely messed up if you try to use the id of an existing element as the hash. So I guess you have to either choose between not using any ids at all, or just using ids.

Answer (score -1):

GWT provides history management. It is also an integral part of their MVP framework. They have also enhanced the history API with places and activities.