# Change DOM with object when clicking the BACK or FORWARD button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hashtag

**Web Setup**

- I have `tab-pane` that are active.
- Elements that bounce to other elements and trigger other `tabs`.
- Using Bootstrap and jquery.

**GOALS**

- When user clicks a navigation link I store the elements `ID` and the active `PANE` into the URL as a hash.  `http://www.mywebsite.com/#pane#id`
- I'd like to store this into the browser history so when the user presses the `BACK` or `FORWARD` button I can pull down that `BACK` url parse out the location activate the `PANE` and `scrollTop` to the element `ID'.
- Obviously when the `BACK` or `FORWARD` button leaves our domain I'd like to warn the user before leaving the page.
- I would like this to work on browsers `IE8` and forward.  Current `FireFox`, `CHROME` and `OPERA`.
- BONUS if this would work in Mobile Webviews.

**Research**

- I found the links and projects below but I'm not sure if these are the most current or best solutions to my problem.

https://github.com/blixt/js-hash

[Keeping history of hash/anchor changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078501/keeping-history-of-hash-anchor-changes-in-javascript)

[How to get the anchor from the URL using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery)

**Questions**

- Is this even possible as I read that you can't change the `BROWSER HISTORY` -- which makes sense.
- Are the above projects a good fit or is there a better solution that can meet my wish list?
- Is it possible to create a global jquery click listener that runs before any of my other listeners that simply gets the element `ID` and active `PANE` then stores them into an `Array`.  I would simply intercept the back/forward button events grab that Array object and set the DOM from it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're not allowed to override the behavior of the `BACK` and `FORWARD` buttons.

Comment: You basically have to constantly watch for the hash to change, and update your page accordingly. You don't even get notified (there is no event) when it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Change HASH on clicking NAV buttons. 
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  //hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

  $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top});
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    _ignoreHashChange = true;
    console.log(this.hash);

  });
});

    // Updating the dom with hashchange.
//_ignoreHashChange = true; //after clicking a butotn. 
_ignoreHashChange = false;
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
    if(_ignoreHashChange === false ){
        if ( window.location.hash.split('#')[1].length ) {
            if ( window.location.hash.split('#')[1][0] !== "." ) {
                $('.nav-tabs a[href="#'+ window.location.hash.split('#')[1] +'"]')[1].tab('show');
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top});
            }
            else {
                $(window.location.hash.split('#')[1]).trigger("click");
            }
            _ignoreHashChange = false;
        }
    }
    _ignoreHashChange = false;
});
```